# Clarification of using a .php file in an image tag

Tags: php, html, image, rest

Sorry for this almost duplicate question, but its a question about a concept used in an answer to my previous question [PHP Base 64 Image data not working in image tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375236/php-base-64-image-data-not-working-in-image-tag)

When i make the index.html file and the getpicture.php file, the index.html shows up as a broken image. When I inspect it I see the source as the getpicture.php, so I somehow doubt that getpicture.php is actually firing off. Is there anywhere to validate that it has actually done something? For all I know its just not even calling the .php file

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since an image on the web is its own document, you can access the image location with your browser by entering the full URL in the address bar. Enter the full URL to your php image script and make sure you're doing error reporting when you troubleshoot. When your image displays in your browser by accessing the URL directly, then you can use that URL in your .html file for an image.